# Compare two numbers given as strings

Tags: code-golf, string, number, decision-problem, parsing

I have a problem at work. I need to compare two numbers that come as strings from two different databases. The numbers may come with leading zeroes and/or leading/trailing spaces. So I may have `"0001 "` from one database and `" 1  "` from the other one.

I solved the problem in C# with the following code:

> `Func<string, string, bool> f = (a,b) => int.Parse(a.Trim()) == int.Parse(b.Trim())`

**The challenge**

This is a really simple challenge, suitable for beginners and any kind of esoteric languages. Given two numbers as strings that may come with leading zeroes and/or leading/trailing spaces, write the shortest code that checks if the two strings represent the same number.

- The inputs need to be two strings or the equivalent in your language (a char array is OK), and they will always represent integer values greater than zero.
- The output must be any two consistent values that represent a truthy value and a falsey value.

**Examples**

```
A          B          Result
----------------------------
"0001"     "1    "    true
"1450"     "1450 "    true
"0010001 " " 10001  " true
"0010000"  "  10  "   false
"101023"   "101024"   false
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code for each language win!

Comment: [...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123808/test-if-two-numbers-are-equal)

Comment: As least it isn't inspired by your kids this time...

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing my own work is my second source of inspiration. I know this is a very simple challenge, but I think these easy challenges are also needed sometimes. I'll try to come up with something more difficult next time.

Comment: By the way, it seems that my work-inspired challenges are either too easy or [too hard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/150587/70347)...

Comment: @JonathanAllan no, each input string will represent only one number. There won't be any spaces inbetween the strings.

Comment: Related sub-problem: [Test if two numbers are equal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123808/test-if-two-numbers-are-equal): just the compare part, with the inputs already as a numeric type.  (Too trivial for codegolf in most languages; only a few languages like Brainfuck have interesting answers).

Comment: In your C# solution, is `Trim()` necessary? As far as I can tell, `int.Parse` can handle white space.

Comment: @Ayb4btu no, it's most probably not needed, but I wrote the code like that on purpose so that people could golf my C# answer.

Comment: Another task: guess the DBs. I call SAP to be one of them.

Comment: ah ok @charlie, I just wrote that shorter c# solution before reading these comments

Answer (score 22):

## [Javascript](https://www.javascript.com/), 11 bytes

```
a=>b=>+a==b
```

Abusing Javascript's casting rules a bit; `+a` coerces `a` into a numeric type.

*-6 bytes* thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152860/compare-two-numbers-given-as-strings/152873?noredirect=1#comment373423_152873) and [Martin Ender♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152860/compare-two-numbers-given-as-strings/152873?noredirect=1#comment373424_152873)

Also a cool take by [LiefdeWen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152860/compare-two-numbers-given-as-strings/152873?noredirect=1#comment373425_152873):

```
a=>b=>~~a==~~b
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. You can do this in 11 bytes using currying and by only converting one of the inputs to an integer: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqHxv8LWrtLWTrvC1rbyv6aGkoKBhRKQAhKa/wE Note as well that, unless a function references itself, you don't need to include the variable assignment in your byte count.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unnamed functions are fine so you don't need `c=`, and currying is also fine so you can use `a=>b=>...` instead of `(a,b)=>`. Finally, my JavaScript is a bit rusty, but I think something like `!(a-b)` would also work?

Comment: The same bytes but it looks much cooler is `~~a==~~b`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the warm welcome and the cool tips!
For some reason I didn't realize that currying could be used to actually save bytes. I'll update the answer in a minute. Thanks again! :)

Comment: See the [tips for golfing in ES6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37624/58974) (and [general JS golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2682/58974)) for more tricks to squeeze bytes out of your solutions.

Comment: The cool versiopn is cool but limited in scope, try input '9123456789' and '533522197'. These are string rapresentation of integer values, are well inside the valid range of integers in javascript (but more than 32 bit)

Comment: Your text no longer matches the code; there's no subtraction.  You're coercing `a` to a numeric type with unary `+`.

Comment: You are right, updated.

Answer (score 20):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/8P9/AwNDAyBW4FKA0AoA)

**Explanation**

Comparison for equality `Q` will automatically try to evaluate strings as ints before comparing.

Comment: Oh really? And I thought `|0+Q` was short enough...

Answer (score 20):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, 33 bytes

```
f={call format(["%1==%2"]+_this)}
```

**Call with:**

```
hint format["%1\n%2\n%3\n%4\n%5",
    ["0001", "1    "] call f,
    ["1450", "1450 "] call f,
    ["0010001 ", " 10001  "] call f,
    ["0010000", "  10  "] call f,
    ["101023", "101024"] call f]
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Alternative version (41 bytes):

```
f={{t=call _x;r=t==s;s=t}forEach _this;r}
```

Still 5 bytes shorter than the more straightforward `f={t=_this;call(t select 0)==call(t select 1)}`

**39 bytes:**

```
f={{t=call _x;r=t==s;s=t}count _this;r}
```

`count` (which returns the size of an array) works instead of `forEach`, because you can give it a "lambda" that is used as a condition to count only the array elements that meet that condition. The "condition" used in this case is not a valid condition, but it doesn't matter here because it doesn't cause an error and the return value of the `count` is not needed.

Comment: I like the variety of situations you take screenshots of your code in.

Answer (score 13):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 488 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:n 1 l 1 l 1 l.Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.'1' is waiting at Writer's Depot.[b]'0' is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:n 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVHLCsIwELz7FYOX3kLrsUcfeFRQ8CAe0rJtF0tSk0j162v6UHyA4sKy7DCZ2TBOXrhplhpOY62twyrLOKW4RoTSt2mnWHN6PFeQqKS1pHIyyDWrvH21LQhTmVCZsS3IXP8j987vcGzv9l/VFqezLAOLmTaK/qL2tq9grAbTrsWmZpcWLa0qpcI4GYMzKA2tCGxRS3ZeXARR8LRCOuwMOzJed06VdmKfHILwB6e/5xV83PP9Z0@pic8cVZfhZMixacIwCn2NgHbC1w0)

Ungolfed:

```
Go to Post Office: west 1st left 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: south 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Equal's Corner: north 1st left 1st left 1st left.
Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.
'1' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
[b]
'0' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: north 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
```

Taxi is (relatively) well-suited to this challenge because strings are the only input or output type allowed. `The Babelfishery` is what converts strings to number (and vice versa) and it handles stripping all the spaces and leading zeroes. It will also handle negative numbers if the `-` is immediately before the first digit. After that, `Equal's Corner` checks the two values against each other and `Writer's Depot` provides the output in string format. Output is `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey.

Comment: Nice one! Just out of curiosity, why is the debug window showing the message `error: The boss couldn't find your taxi in the garage.  You're fired!`?

Comment: @Charlie Taxi requires you to drive back to the taxi garage when you're done with your route. If you don't bring the car back, you get fired. (You also have to be sure to stop and refuel every now and then or you run out of gas.) In [tag:code-golf] questions that don't disallow output to STDERR, I generally don't worry about getting fired. You can add this to get rid of the error if you don't want to lose your job: `Go to Taxi Garage:n 1 r 1 l 1 r.`

Comment: This answer and its comments are totally surrealistic. I love this community.

Comment: @RightLeg My [favorite Taxi program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139939/38183) I've written took me two weeks and a lot of debugging. You really want a trip, though? Check out [Shakespeare](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/#SECTION00090000000000000000).

Answer (score 10):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 27 bytes

```c
f(s,t){s=atoi(s)==atoi(t);}
```

With `-O0` (which is the default setting).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BCoMwEEX3nmIIFDJgIVG7Em/SjUSULExLk5149vgzbts6m3nMPD7f3Rfncp51rBNvcRjTy@vIwwmJ@z37kGgdfdBcbRVh3h@cZq1u0zOomkDGGAtStrwVc//Ds93DiIf9z0NciaTi0onXuiQT9K8uniQV4DatlCjUibrnAw)

## C, 32 bytes

```c
f(s,t){return atoi(s)==atoi(t);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY67CsMwDEX3fIUwFCxIwW7TKeRPugS3KR7qFkeZQr7dvVbXPrToIB0uN@xvIZQy2bkVXvNVlpxolEe0Mw@DgnC/lZiE7mNMlpu1Icwz4zRZs7uck2kJ5JzzIOPr2zD3XzzfnZx62L88xNVIqi698b@uyQT9o4snaQW4h6OWqNSpupUX)

Comment: In the debug window you can see that the types of `s` and `t` default to `int`, but still you can pass strings as parameters? C will always amaze me...

Comment: @Charlie In C, strings are arrays of `char`, and when you pass an array to a function you actually just pass the pointer to the first element of the array. Here, the pointers to the `char` arrays are implicitly converted to integers when passed to the function, and the integers are converted back to pointers when calling `atoi`.

Comment: which could blow up horribly on a platform where pointers are wider than ints ... just saying, of course it's fine for site standards here :)

Comment: If you want to use ridiculous crap like `s=foo;` instead of `return foo;` you need to label this as "x86 gcc with optimization disabled", not just "C", because this code doesn't return a value except as an implementation artefact.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, yeah. I'm not a big fan of "returning" this way, either, but you see it on this site a lot (because answers here can have undefined behaviour as long as they work seemingly consistently) and it's always just labeled as `C (gcc)`. I added the `x86`, but because `-O0` is the default for gcc, the "optimizations disabled" doesn't need to be explicitly mentioned.

Comment: In the real world, most people who build code with gcc do so with optimization enabled (usually with a `CFLAGS=` setting in a Makefile that came with the code...).  x86 gcc implies (to me) that the code uses some C extensions that gcc provides, like `__builtin_ia32_crc32qi` (for the CRC32 instruction), and will work with any gcc options.  i.e. the word GCC means "Gnu Compile Collection", not that it only works with a bare `gcc` command, and not with any options.  I think the hack is dumb, and we shouldn't let people get away with it without a big ugly warning label to show how hacky it is.

Comment: I went looking to see if there were any architectures where `s=retval;` instead of `return retval;` actually broke.  It looks like gcc's internal logic (with `-O0` only) actually treats the last expression as the return value, maybe the same way that [a GNU C statement-expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) works.   (But it does require `s=`). On ARM32, it calculates the `==` result in `r3`, and then uses an extra `mov r0, r3` to make that the return value!  So it's not an x86-specific hack, it's a `gcc -O0` hack that gcc seems to go out of its way to support.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/44nzQy

Comment: For `f(s,t)`, if `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int)` this will fail, such as on old Windows with 16 bit integers but 32 bit `FAR` pointers, and [here is an example on more modern architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384672/1270789).

Comment: @KenY-N You're missing the entire point of c code golf. It's about finding those specific hacky edge cases where you can input the minimum amount of code and get the results you want, not providing a portable experience.

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 4 bytes

```
=&do
```

Compare `=` after `&` evaluating `do`. Can also be `=&".` 
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8FWTUnvf2pyRr6CuoGBgaG6AhikAbG6IYgFFuCCKDA0MTVAUQDkoygAGgAyBCQGVqAA4QIZKArAhkAUAFVA7IBZAVRgZKyOsALENwHx/wMA)

Comment: Interestingly enough this will work for both negatives as other languages understand them (e.g. `-10`) and negatives as J understands them (e.g. `_10`) due to the way monadic `-` works.

Answer (score 7):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 11 bytes

```
.+
$*
D`
¶$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg819Pm0tFi8slgevQNpX//w0MDAx1DBWAgMvQxNRAB0QocAEFQRIKOgoQGiZioKMAFAGpBXKNjHXAlAkA)

Input is linefeed separated, but the test suite uses comma separation for convenience. Prints `1` for equality and `0` for inequality.

#### Explanation

```
.+
$*
```

Convert each line to unary. This ignores leading zeros and spaces.

```
D`
```

Deduplicate: clear the second line if both are the same.

```
¶$
```

Check that the string now ends in a linefeed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 22 bytes

```
(([{}]{})[{(){}}](){})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0Mjuro2trpWM7paQ7O6tjYWRGr@/29gYGgAxFwKYEoBAA)

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king).

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0Mjuro2trpWM7paQ7O6tjYWRGr@/29gYGgAxFwKYEoBAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:int(a)==int(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY49DsMgDIV3TmF5ChWDadIlEiehDKAWNVJLosCS01NMVKlenvW955/tKK81jTWae337T3h48CrMSyqDl8awBlnLM5cMBqxFItKoADW0Qqcs6ulGqLqcoCU4BRyDs/03qPNm/OYbvY59J3cTOidEXHfgq7CkrnkWsO38ThwuDKSsXw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity), 17 bytes

```
..)..
.Ii).
@Ii=.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09PU0@PS88zU1OPy8Ez01bv/38DA0MDIOYCkwA)

Triangularity is, for once, competitive!

#### How it works

Triangularity requires the code to have a triangular distribution of the dots. That is, the length of each row must be equal the number of rows multiplied by 2 and decremented, and each row must have (on each side) a number of dots equal to its position in the program (the bottom row is row 0, the one above it is row 1 and so forth). Keeping this in mind, let's analyse how the code works:

```
..).. || Push a 0 onto the stack.
.Ii   || Get the 0th input and cast it to an integer.
   ). || Push another 0 onto the stack.
@I    || Increment the ToS => 1. Get the first input.
  i=. || Then cast it to an integer and compare their equality.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @Adám*

```apl
=/⍎¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRb/Ue9fYdWADkK6gYGBobqCuqGCkCgzgUUMDQxNVCHUArqIFEusCpDkEKggLoChAVkICRAGhSAEgpgHWBTgOJGxupQhglIGAA)

Comment: [`=/⍎¨`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRb/Ue9fYdWADkK6gYGBobqCuqGCkCgzgUUMDQxNVCHUArqIFEusCpDkEKggLoChAVkICRAGhSAEgpgHWBTgOJGxupQhglIGAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 3 bytes

```
¥Vn
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=pVZu&input=IjA4IiAKIiA4ICI=)

Converts the second input to an integer and compares equality with the first.

Answer (score 3):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 7 bytes

```
X/n
o@i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/z9CP48r3yHz/38DAwNDLkMFIAAA)

Any non-digit separator works. Prints `1` for equality and `0` otherwise.

#### Explanation

```
X   XOR, does nothing.
/   Switch to Ordinal mode.
i   Read all input as a string.
/   Switch to Cardinal mode.
X   XOR. Implicitly finds all integers in the string and pushes them separately
    onto the stack. The XOR gives 0 if the values are identical.
n   Logical NOT. Gives 1 for equal inputs and 9 otherwise.
/   Switch to Ordinal.
o   Print the 0 or 1 as a string.
/   Switch to Cardinal.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 3):

## jq, 24 characters

```
map(tonumber)|.[0]==.[1]
```

The 2 strings are passed as items of an array.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq 'map(tonumber)|.[0]==.[1]' <<< '["0010001 ", " 10001  "]'
true

bash-4.4$ jq 'map(tonumber)|.[0]==.[1]' <<< '["0010000", "  10  "]'
false
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z83sUCjJD@vNDcptUizRi/aINbWVi/aMPb//2glAwNDAyBWUNJRUFKAMBWUYgE) ([All test cases](https://tio.run/##lY7NCsIwEITP9imWPbVQQ6L1UuiTxByqRlD6Z5qCYH11Y7ZFKUUPzSU7y3w7c705x6SCHtDq1oJ/KexDRiLCGNDotivsZNuXeRPauurKgzZRzyRXWcakUINd3xt9tPo02D8iwpVzMqDjjyEGU5DIORdIO48J@kmoyQ3vsqbT8IznqEh2/Iv6eQHqQykYqCyMI@AS1AcT6tmh8Qw950WrfxT26GaLY2Gak39ooF51Yy911bq1eQM))

Answer (score 3):

## Excel VBA, <strike>27</strike> 16 Bytes

-9 Thanks to @Nayrb and @TaylorScott

```
[C1]=[A1]-[B1]=0
```

Where you input the values on the Cells with `'string`.

<strike>Where `x` and `y` are the input Strings and `z` is a Boolean output.</strike>

If CInt(x)=CInt(y) Then z=1

Using [CInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/type-conversion-functions)

Comment: Why not: z=x-y=0?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is invalid as it does not take input and rather relies on having predefined values ([which has been deemed against the community's rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14117/61846)) and outputing to a variable ([which is also against community rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?page=3&tab=active#tab-top))

Comment: As for a valid solution perhaps a vbe immediate window function such as  `?[Int(A1)=Int(B1)]` that takes input from the ranges `A1` and `B1` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
¤=r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vcGhbrtujpsb/h5bYFv3//z9aQ8nAwMBQSUfJUAEIlDR1NJQMTUwNQAJACiIAVABSpAAUVICwkMVBahWA4jDdQEEjY5B@EMNESTMWAA)

#### Explanation

```
¤    -- combine both arguments of ..
 =   -- .. equality ..
  r  -- .. with read
```

Comment: If you take input as a two-element list, `Ër` works too.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 20 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)+$a-eq$b
```

Similar to the JavaScript answer, just longer because PowerShell doesn't have currying. Uses `+` to cast the first string to integer, and then the `-eq`uals automatically casts the second string to integer. Output is True/False.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVJU1slUTe1UCXp////6gYGBobq/9UVDBUU1AE)

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, 35 bytes

[Per our standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341), data is input via pre-existing table `t` with `varchar` fields `a` and `b`.

```sql
    SELECT IIF(ABS(a)=ABS(b),1,0)FROM t
```

Returns `1` if they match, `0` if they don't.

A few of SQL's mathematical functions (including `ABS`, `FLOOR` and `CEILING`) will do an implicit conversion to numeric if given string parameters, this is shorter than an explicit `CAST(a AS INT)` or `CONVERT(INT,b)`, and works in this case since we know the input values are always positive.

`IIF` is specific to MS SQL 2012 and above, so no guarantee about other implementations.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
t€⁶V€€ḌE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/kUdOaR43bwkBU05qHO3pc////H61kYGBgqKSjoGSoAARKsQA) or see the **[test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/kUdOaR43bwkBU05qHO3pc/x9uB7Ii//@PVjIwMDBU0lFQMlQAAqVYHYVoJUMTUwOwEJCGCgEVgRQqgIQVIEwUGZB6oAxQCm4IUNzIGGwMiGWiFAsA)**

35 answers, and no Jelly submission? Takes the argument as a list (`["0001", "1    "]` for the first example)

### How it works

```
t€⁶V€€ḌE - Main link. Argument: list       e.g.    ["0001", "1    "]
 €       - For €ach element...                     ["0001", "1"]
t        -   trim from both sides...
  ⁶      -   spaces
     €   - For €ach element...
   V€    -   evaluate €ach character               [[0, 0, 0, 1], [1]]
      Ḍ  - Convert from digits                     [1, 1]
       E - Are they equal?                         1
```

Comment: Isn't this surprisingly long for Jelly?

Comment: @Charlie `V` (eval) is evil, meaning that it can't use the same approach as most other submissions

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 8 bytes

```
=A1-B1=0
```

Excel does the string to num conversion for us.

(To input as string, prefix values with `'`.)

Answer (score 3):

## Q (Kdb+), 13 bytes

```
=/["J"$(x;y)]
```

### Explanation

(x;y) : a list of the two inputs.

"J"$ :  casting each input to a long (7j) type from string (10c), which can correctly interpret
           white space and  leading 0s.

=/ : checks equality over elements in a list (each subsequent pair).
As there is only one pair, returns single boolian 0b/1b.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Usually, a link to an online interpreter/compiler is appreciated, and if not obvious, an explanation as well.

Comment: Thanks!
Explanation added there.
I doubt there is an online interpreter for q, I did a quick look and couldn't find one.

Comment: I would say that this should be written as a lambda including the curly braces, i.e. `{=/["J"$(x;y)]}` for *15 bytes*... Although for 8 bytes you could have this: `(~/)"J"$` if you are just using the REPL and passing the inputs as a list of strings... or `{(~/)"J"$x}` for **11** as a function.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 19 bytes

```powershell
$args-join'-eq'|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL1YNys/M09dN7VQvSYzteL////qCkBgAALmlgrq/9WBpII6AA)

`-join` the argument array (`$args`) with the string representation of the comparison operator (`-eq`) then evaluate the expression with `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`).

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how you get by without needing to cast to integer, whereas mine breaks if I remove the `+` since it's doing string equality checking.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork because I'm essentially generating PowerShell code and then executing it, and since leading zeroes and leading/trailing spaces don't matter for the interpreter, it "just works". If the 2 numbers are `00009  ` and `077 ` then the resultant code is `00009  -eq077 `, a perfectly valid piece of code. You're dealing directly with the string at runtime, so you must cast it first so the operation is done on a numeric.

Comment: Right, yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```r
!diff(as.double(scan(,'')))
```

Reads numbers as strings, converts them to doubles and checks if their difference is not zero.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XzElMy1NI7FYLyW/NCknVaM4OTFPQ0ddXVNT87@6goIBEBgZKyioK6gbGav/BwA)

*−1 byte thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)*

Comment: Just `""` is sufficient

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 20 bytes

*-11 bytes thanks to Laikoni. -2 bytes thanks to Zgarb.*

```hs
a#b=0+read a==read b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY07DoBACER7TzFBOxvWT7mHwWii8Rv1/uuimxg/NDDMY2hl65thcE7iynK6NlJDrD175UbpJljUcwRfy9pNOxIQMxvSDWKQAT1dU5R8u168AX@tCSAFEOY/RGMu5PPD@1lO4YeKgtwB)

Comment: @Laikoni It's even better to not bind `read`: `a#b=0+read a==read b`

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 20 bytes

```lua
print(...-arg[2]==0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDT09PN7EoPdoo1tbWQPP///8KCgYGpqYK/01NAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500 BASIC, ~29 tokenized BASIC bytes

New solution thanks to Neil (thanks for the tip).

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 INPUT B$
 3 PRINT VAL A$=VAL B$
```

This solution requires user input, so enter in two strings with white spaces and/or leading zeros, or enter two strings of non-equal numeric value; `0` is false and `1` is true once line three has compared the value of each string entered.

#### Old solution: Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500 BASIC, ~46 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 LET A$=" 001 "
 2 LET B$="1"
 3 PRINT (VAL A$=VAL B$)
```

The actual check is done in line three, which is only ~16 tokenized BASIC bytes; so entering each test case pair using direct mode will save ~30 bytes from the listing. Note that this byte count does not include the `var stack`.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `INPUT A$` and `INPUT B$`? Also I don't think you need the `()`s.

Comment: Yes, I could use that also - I just wanted a proof of concept

Answer (score 2):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 21 characters

```
*\n*=@cmpn{*;*;0;1;0}
```

No boolean in Gema. As the `@get-switch{}`/`@set-switch{}` functions use 0 and 1 to represent switch statuses, also used 0 and 1.

The 2 strings are passed on separate input lines.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '*\n*=@cmpn{*;*;0;1;0}' <<< $'0010001\n10001  '
1

bash-4.4$ gema '*\n*=@cmpn{*;*;0;1;0}' <<< $'0010000\n  10  '
0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, 9 + 1 (`-p`) = 10 bytes

```
$_=$_==<>
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3haIbG3s/v83MDAwVAABLkMIaWJqoIBgcQGlwUq4FCA0TMSASwEoAlIG5BoZQyiTf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 8 bytes

```
[#~\#~=]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzRCsIwDEXf@xUXKmQDLaluLwPF/5gDh/ZJxDK71/16TSpDbEo4nOTmncbbI9xz7u1ysctxyOcuGFMZoCJm9gR95Euvi/ZNy6sWXLUsawAk9aX/iWbke/4dEr8/UDmk2Iiv0cusw2YKccJzjKCtxOwVcU4Cu5M0ReccAl5zMoOu5Q8)

### Explanation

```
[#~\#~=]   anonymous function
 #~        eval TOS
   \       swap top two
    #~     eval TOS
      =    push equality of top two
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), <strike>80</strike> <strike>79</strike> 78 bytes

```
import Foundation;func r(g:[NSString])->Bool{return g[0].intValue==g[1].intValue}
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/TIHU59893)

Comment: Welcome to the site! As Uriel mentioned, this currently counts as a snippet, rather than a function or full program, as it assumes the input is stored in variables. You should change this to be in accordance to [these](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) I/O rules. Also, you can check out these [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79203/tips-for-golfing-in-swift) for golfing in Swift!

Comment: @Uriel Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 11 bytes

```
Same@Map&:N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3vkpqWmZcarZKm8z84MTfVwTexQM3K738sV0BRZl6JQ5qCrZ1CWDSXApBQMjAwMFTSUVAyVFCK1YEIGZqYGoCFgDRCFKgOpFYBJKMAZaLKGUClkEwCihsZg80CsUyUYrli/wMA)

This takes an array of strings, such as `V["0001", "1   "]`. Simply stated, `Map&:N` is a function that maps `N` over its argument, and `Same` checks that the array contains only equal members. (Fun fact: this function works for more than 2 string arguments.)

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 12 bytes

```
{$0=$1==$2}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/WsXAVsXQ1lbFqNbw/38DAwNDBUMuQxNTAwUQwQXkQ8RAJJQHlDLgMgQyjYwVwJQJAA)

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 9 bytes

```
$0=$1==$2
```

Alternate version: outputs `1` on match, otherwise outputs nothing

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcBWxdDWVsXo/38DAwNDBUMuQxNTAwUQwQXkQ8RAJJQHlDLgMgQyjYwVwJQJAA)

Comment: Oftentimes nothing is not considered a falsey value. If this is run on mutliline input, it's not possible to tell which lines fail. Just my $0.02. Adding `{}1` would print the `0` falsey values.

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 42 bytes

```
	OUTPUT =EQ(EVAL(INPUT),EVAL(INPUT)) 1
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NCQgNETB1jVQwzXM0UfD0w/I1dRBYmsqGHK5@rn8/29gYGgABFwKCoYGCgoA)

Outputs 1 for truthy, nothing for falsey. Since  (space) is the concatenation operator in SNOBOL, `EVAL`ing a number with leading/trailing spaces yields the number itself, and it also neatly takes care of any leading zeroes. `EQ` tests for numerical equality, conditionally setting `OUTPUT` to 1 on `Success`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/java8-2100321.html), <s>58</s> 51 bytes

#### 7 bytes thanks to Kevin

```
b->c->new Long(b.trim()).equals(new Long(c.trim()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdA/T4QwGAbwnU/x5qY2kQb0nE4ZHJx0cjQOpRSuUFq8ljMXc58dy5@eejDA1PR50t/7UtIjDXXDVZlVXdOmUjBgkhoDr1Qo@A4AwFhq3XXpqqS1QpK8VcwKrcjzdHh4swehiptVnSetJacqSYDCI3RpmLAwUfwLXrQqUEpcrUYYE/7ZUmnQJWE@wd0ucHNN007THbXIoHYzo9F5/wB6KAweVxi@MQDm1E0URfFmdx1lfRT3F3@zk7G8Jrq1pHEtKxWihDaNPCGGp0OG8TDTv9f48Nr2PppDuY9WQtxD@RJUjBvF/VIwx/Z9DGO60iu8t1/yxK8XLXjl4DlwrSa8Vi5p1fCvnHZ7N7fkJdyusypvyd7qy@fg3P0A)

### Explanation

Trims off spaces, casting to Long removes leading zeros, and then returns boolean value if they are equal or not.

Comment: You can save a byte by using currying: `b->c->` instead of `(b,c)->`. In addition, the trailing semi-colon doesn't have to be counted with Java/.NET lambdas. [Try it online: **56 bytes**](https://tio.run/##jdA9b4MwEAbgnV9xyoSlYkGbTikMHTq1U8eqgzEfMRjbwiZSVOW3UxtwPxIGPJ38nvzcuSEnEklViqZoRzXknFGgnGgNb4QJ@AoAQBti7HVjW/FgGMfVIKhhUuCXpXh6Nz0T9d2mnmcpeUlElgGBFMY8ymiUvUpRY0V6XboqzLFt7kKE0vQqoT4ZD4Edbhl5GfEkWQGdHTycsY9PIH2t0bzHdOYAqKV3cRwnu8N1VLgocRd/s7M2ZYflYLCyXYaLkGCiFD@HFC1FgdA007/Xyum1/WN8C1U@2giVHqrWoHreKHFLwS12dDHM6Uav9t5xzWO/XrziNZNnwa0a81qzprXTX1nt/uHW4j/hfpvVeos7yzVfgsv4DQ)

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##jdA/T4QwGAbwnU/x5qY2kQb0nE4ZHJx0cjQOpRSuUFq8ljMXc58dy5@eejDA1PR50t/7UtIjDXXDVZlVXdOmUjBgkhoDr1Qo@A4AwFhq3XXpqqS1QpK8VcwKrcjzdHh4swehiptVnSetJacqSYDCI3RpmLAwUfwLXrQqUEpcrUYYE/7ZUmnQJWE@wd0ucHNN007THbXIoHYzo9F5/wB6KAweVxi@MQDm1E0URfFmdx1lfRT3F3@zk7G8Jrq1pHEtKxWihDaNPCGGp0OG8TDTv9f48Nr2PppDuY9WQtxD@RJUjBvF/VIwx/Z9DGO60iu8t1/yxK8XLXjl4DlwrSa8Vi5p1fCvnHZ7N7fkJdyusypvyd7qy@fg3P0A) by using `new Long(...)` instead of `Long.parseLong(...)`

Comment: Had to check the docs, cause I did not think equals would work, but it does, Long equals checks value not the object

Comment: @dwana Yea, I wish `==` didn't compare objects or I could have used that and saved a few bytes :P

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (NARS2000)](http://www.nars2000.org/), 7 bytes

```
=⍥⍎
```

Well, yes, I do know NARS2000 can't compete over Dyalog here since it uses Unicode, but I thought I'd rather show off `⍥` (called **Composition** in NARS2000, even though it's actually unrelated to function composition), something Dyalog doesn't have as a built-in and I haven't ever seen used here. In Dyalog, it has to be implemented as `{(⍵⍵⍺)⍺⍺⍵⍵ ⍵}`. What it does is call the right operand monadic function on both the left and right argument, and then call the left operand dyadic function on the results.

Here, the right operand is `⍎` (**Execute**, i.e. eval) and the left operand is `=` (**Equal To**, i.e. check if its arguments are equal).

Comment: Are composition and execute supposed to render as whitespace?

Comment: @JohnDvorak um, no? They're not whitespace, the second char is U+2365 APL FUNCTIONAL SYMBOL CIRCLE DIAERESIS and the third is U+234E APL FUNCTIONAL SYMBOL DOWN TACK JOT.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Whatever font you're viewing this in may not have symbols for those codepoints.

Comment: @Οurous I highly suspect that's the case too, but if you're using well-updated software you shouldn't have any problem viewing such chars.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```r
pryr::f(as.double(x)==as.double(y))
```

There's probably some cleverer way to coerce strings to numerics but I haven't figured it out yet.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/oKiyyMoqTSOxWC8lvzQpJ1WjQtPWFsGr1NT8n6ahZGBgYKiko6BkqAAESppcYCFDoKgBSFRBwdAAJPwfAA)

Comment: `as.double` is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 2 + 3 = 5 bytes

```
=n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3zbv////umX/DQwMDQwVoOA/jKGAJAgA)

Uses the `-v` flag to pass the values into the program. This automatically converts them to numbers, removing the spaces and leading 0s. It then outputs if the two are equal, and exits with an error as it tries to compare an empty stack.

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 9 bytes

```
[1p]sQ?=Q
```

Outputs 1 if the numbers are equal, or nothing if unequal. The input numbers are separated by ',', and this gives a warning since data is code in dc. I wasn't sure if space was allowed as delimiter, so I chose one that doesn't stop the program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z/asCC2ONDeNvD/fwUFAwMTBR0gCaIVFAA)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 89 bytes

```
@call:c %1
@set e=%errorlevel%
@call:c %2
@if %e%==%errorlevel% echo 1
:c
@exit/b%~1
```

Prints `1` if the two numbers are the same. Explanation: Batch's numeric processing usually uses leading zeros to indicate an octal number, however `exit/b` always takes a decimal number. The `~` removes any quotes that would be needed to pass leading or trailing spaces in the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 23  bytes

```
s=->x,y{x.to_i==y.to_i}
```

Comment: Usage: s.call("0123", "123")

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 45 bytes

```
proc x a\ b {expr [scan $a %d]==[scan $b %d]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5LCsMwDET3PsUgkr3cJsucJM3CdrtLG5OkYAg@uyvlQyUhRo8Z0BrGUuI8BSS4Bzy2V4oz@iW4DyqH@jl03Xl5vXIZ3y6eXmJmS9Aiu29Dtmn5QiIViUmNIOlD/al6ZSwfYWG3O@1hlQ2ZjC1@1wV90n8qP2RTfg)

Comment: Failed outgolf `proc x L {expr [join [lmap n $L {scan $n %d}] ==]}` on https://tio.run/##TcsxCsMwDAXQPaf4iHS323TMDXoD4yG4HlpSxyQpGIzO7koNhWrR5@lrD3NreV0CCm6oseQV7rk8Etz8mjISeuEtTBISTnf2GEfP7XuMqJWMMZZAFjLEqGSHq1GQdYAUtARBHOnftQvx37fg@aL/GgZiwS6/9w2uoI@@4/YB has **50 bytes**

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 4 bytes

```perl6
*==*
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##VY/hTcMwEIX/e4onCyE7pI4DpT8IaTsEC4TgSpGc1MQ2ApUuA3N0po4Q7ASiYlmn53t3352N6vVq8FbhbSXqgrQfuO58q/qmXqhXX2mUQ1KWyTBaW6esQwnddMoyLtrKPOAAUe/bZ5bhfPqi59M3HplINnw9vzOeYpO53qsMRxKHPQVOQYyuOtyM0ILs9v0vf7EG2zad8S69Uu9G1U69cBwI0Fj8W459TnWBP1emoFNSmPA3xiNuNik5DlRKmVPEQ/MxxhC3IzRf3ss/K8hLKzTFxpCimFQQl1ZsDDeXE3FXaRuJwbu9oyMxyuXs/QA)

The `==` operator converts to Numeric which ignores leading and trailing whitespace, and leading `0`'s get ignored just the same. (`0o127` is how you write an octal)

The two `*` are just there to turn it into a lambda that takes two arguments.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 26 bytes

```julia
~x=parse(Int,x);a%b=~a==~b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCoMwEIZ3n@I4EBLIYKxdWgLVrXsHwTpEaqklRDFKnXx1e1FaaG@4fJfv7n@OptFyWpZ5Up3uXc3OdhATP@qwUrNWaq6Wk3u0L0CIqJIYiEJAIgyCrm/sYCzDq73UbnDQaefq2wFQgDaGFWmYKZXDve2BpSITOYfGQhEwpDBJW75Qrn0dhn6sOWmZ7KOvJv7TdOwD/C/Chp5/9RqAQN4/xHdt3JZOPt6tkRsntCY@viw5X94)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 30 bytes

```julia
a%b=eval(Meta.parse("$a==$b"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BCoJAEIbvPsUwKKwg4ZpdgoX03q2DYB5G2shYVFyt3t5mlYKaw@y3883@sPfJNCRf80xBrfSDjDjqkTY9DVYL9Ekpv8YwnA/21j0BIeZKE2AKAJnQ8/qhaUfTCjy3J21HCz1Zqy97wAjIGFFmQa5UAdduAJFFeVSE0LRQegI5TPKWK5RLXy7jMOmQtUx38Vcz/2l@7ALcFGFFx796CUBg7w7mKxm7prNPtkvkyimvRR9fVfzrNw)

Some meta programming fun, not the shortest solution though

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
qFsM
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qFsM&input=%5B%22%20%20001%20%20%22%2C%20%221%20%20%20%22%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%220001%22%2C%20%221%20%20%20%20%22%5D%0A%5B%221450%22%2C%20%221450%20%22%5D%0A%5B%220010001%20%22%2C%20%22%2010001%20%20%22%5D%0A%5B%220010000%22%2C%20%22%20%2010%20%20%22%5D%0A%5B%22101023%22%2C%20%22101024%22%5D&debug=0)

Int-parse each element of the input list with `sM(Q)`, then `F`old over e`q`uality.

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram Language, 27 bytes

```
ToExpression[#1<>"=="<>#2]&
```

Test cases:

```
In[1]:= ToExpression[#1 <> "==" <> #2] &["0001", "1"]
Out[1]= True

In[2]:= ToExpression[#1 <> "==" <> #2] &["1450", "1450 "]
Out[2]= True

In[3]:= ToExpression[#1 <> "==" <> #2] &["0010001", " 10001"]
Out[3]= True

In[4]:= ToExpression[#1 <> "==" <> #2] &["0010000", "  10  "]
Out[4]= False

In[5]:= ToExpression[#1 <> "==" <> #2] &["101023", "101024"]
Out[5]= False
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 52 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$n=toInt{#c\\c<-n|c>' '}
?n=(==)($n)o$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDoIwEADQna@4xCaFgQSYrSw4kLgxCsPlQNOkvRo5TYz6655Mb3oUFmSNaX6EBSJ6Vh9v6S4wyHzkZ2bYSepZ3jsaR9qX/KGDBfvNWna5c0VuuEhGB8HtOGjhbOvGThsAVVU3YCf90SXgddWyP2n3Yoye1j8)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 65 bytes

```cpp
#include<cstdlib>
auto a(auto b,auto c){return atoi(b)==atoi(c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5BCsMgFET3nuJjNwopmDbdNDEn6cYYW4REQ6KrkLNbtbSrQMnfzMDw/oycpvNLyhBO2sjB96qRi@sH3bVIeGdBkCxdkUXSdVbOzwaEs5p0lPNsJK233wdotF3crMTYIqSNg1FoQyhaEcSL3@93ab2DpgEiCGaMlbgAXKYUU@Ac3OwVTTl@GFzvY2V1YxmLegCLZakQEgofe5jOvRDpL/oUw/J/cGQv1zw5uWof3UJ4Aw)

I initially tried used a lambda expression, but `auto a=[]` is three more characters, and less one more for no trailing semicolon. On the other hand, since `atoi` is not referenced until the lambda is instantiated, could I delete the `#include` and put that in the test harness footer instead?

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 6 bytes

Pretty standard stuff, but using Javascript's auto type casting

```
!(a-b)
```

Or if we don't need it as a function (19 bytes)

```
let f=(a,b)=>!(a-b)
```

Try it online! https://jsfiddle.net/pgz4ctLy/2/

Comment: Welcome to the site! Note that this is quite similar to the [existing Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152873/70347)...

Comment: Thanks @charlie, I saw that answer and I didn't believe it met the requirements of "inputs and output" so I posted this answer. Unfortunately being new to the site I wasn't allowed to comment on the other answer so this seemed like the most suitable option and is different enough to stand as it's own.

Comment: There's a lot of ways you can post a valid answer, and one of them is writing a lambda expression. So a valid answer (using your code) would be just `(a,b)=>-a==-b`. If you use currying, you can write `a=>b=>-a==-b`.

Comment: Just to let you know [even duplicate answers are fine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/8478) (although they're rare).

Comment: I have edited my post to be a bit more unique and shorter ;)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP 5.6+, 16 (42 when callable) bytes

The minimum code that meets the puzzle's requirements (16 bytes):

```
(int)$a==(int)$b
```

In callable form (42 bytes):

```
function f($a,$b){return(int)$a==(int)$b;}
```

[Try it online, with tests](https://3v4l.org/a9EUL)

## Explanation

Declare a regular function with a single-character name `f` with two, otherwise undetermined parameters. It returns the result of comparing both arguments after casting each to integers, which safely removed the padding and whitespace.
The code could have been made 2 bytes shorter by converting the function to a closure, but then the closure would not be assigned (which takes another 3 bytes), and therefore not callable.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! All answers need to be full programs or callable functions (although they may be unnamed function expressions). So the first snippet isn't valid, but the second one is fine.

Comment: @Xano, PHP's type juggling will implicitly convert "numerical looking" strings to numbers, so all you need to do is use the == operator, as long as one is a number.  A 32 byte solution using type-coercion would be: function($a,$b){return$a==0+$b;} TIO: https://tio.run/##ZY7BisMgEIbP9SmGQTBhhZrd9rLW9rZPsLckBxOUFEoSojmVPnt2TMKysB50nO/7dcZuXC63sRuBe7P4uW/jfegzbiVv8ufk4jz13Bqj3nijX4vm0YUYwEDJDiUqpQqUgAXQwlrSfjgeIU6zS7g4ndWK6VzxX0jRFAeUCFuVlP@GSgIZv9jbR9ieJ/7@QXgtTjuGXag1Y36YnG27DPaxbaAKcngy0h73EIlYCbyhniGkU9@13QAChVwZVljFCjFZ@w3MFcrU8NmWzuEG4pumFvAJ4it9T2msqx41ey0/

Answer (score 1):

### Mumps, 7 bytes

```
W +X=+Y
```

In Mumps, all data are strings, the '+' operator evaluates the string to a numeric value. There is no implicit output function, so the 'W' (Write) function provides the output.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 5 bytes

**Solution:**

```
=/.:'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/31Zfz0pdQ8nAwNAAiBWUrJUUICwFJc3//wE)

**Examples:**

```
=/.:'("0001";"1    ")
1
=/.:'("1450";"1450 ")
1
=/.:'("0010001";" 10001  ")
1
=/.:'("0010000";"  10  ")
0
=/.:'("101023";"101024")
0
```

**Explanation:**

Convert each input to an integer, and then check for equality.

```
=/.:' / the solution
  .:' / value (.:) each ('), converts char list to integer
=/    / equality (=) over (/)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 5 bytes

```
'ì'ì=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/1/98Bogsv3/38DAwJDLUEFBAQA)

```
'ì'ì=
'      «read string, push to stack                  »;
 ì     «swap type (integer/string) of top of stack  »;
  'ì   «do it again for the second integer string   »;
    =  «compare for equality                        »;
```

Answer (score 1):

### C# (32 bytes)

```
a=>b=>int.Parse(a)==int.Parse(b)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##jY49C8IwEIb3/oqXTAnU0voxaV0EJwuCg3MaowRqAr0oiPS316QqOKlZ7i48z3unaKRI9Rcy9oTdjbw@z5NENZII1T0ByEtvFK7OHFBJY7mIv3ix2fpi1YJ8G/QU71o71yxxRNlzmdYC5RLG@mwrW9Jchrn8mGvRh7iwFM@3cpZco7N9a7zeGKv5kbM8zwuWghWRYELMv9LFdJYPdKi/6RAd48FShmf3rzMsQZD@uSkY48lwVeymUUA0uqTrHw)

as already mentioned in the comments, you can do it shorter than the C# provided in the question. I wrote this thinking I was clever before reading the reply to the comments by the OP. :)

Comment: The whitespace isn't needed at all, and currying can save an additional byte. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY6xCsIwEIb3PsXRKQEtrdapJovgZEFwcE5jKoGaQC8VRPrsNWkFF9Fmyd3xff@dxKVEOXSozRVOD3TqVkSRbAQilM8IAJ1wWsLd6guUQhtCwxTebLLvjNyia72@@DqrrG04hxrYIBivGNfGJUfRoiKCMvbpKjr4WL8cprezBm2jknOrnTpoo0hN4jRNs5iSOAtETGnxk87yTTrS/v9P@@gQD8GAqZwrjVvAS3OO8sZqPZ4VqjwIEIw@6ocX "C# (Visual C# Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

**R, 55 bytes**

```
V<-strtoi(gsub(" ","",c(A,B),fixed=T),base=9)
V[1]==V[2]
```

This is my first attempt at codegolf; gave it my best try. Suggestions welcome!

Assumptions:

1. The inputs are given as strings A and B
2. The integers contained are less than 1888888888. Larger values will cause strtoi() to return NA.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
"⌊≈
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJcIuKMiuKJiCIsIiIsIlwiMDAwMVwiXG5cIjEgICBcIiJd)

#### Explained

```
"⌊≈
"   # pair both inputs into list
 ⌊  # floor
  ≈ # all items equal?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 9 bytes

```
:*&Z|+:==
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWK6201KJqtK1sofybDQUKbtHRSgYGBoZKOgpKhgpAoBQbywURNjQxNQALA2kkYaBikAYFkJQChIkhC9anAJRFMQ8oZWQMNhHEMgHKQNyxYAGEBgA)

### Explanation

```ruby
:* & Z |       # Map with to_i (Z), then
         +:==  # Compare
```

I think this would be 7 bytes with J-uby’s `**` operator:

```ruby
Z**+:==
```

…but it’s [broken or removed](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby/issues/6) in the current version.

Answer (score 1):

## nroff, 51 bytes

1 and 0 for truthy and falsey.
Wish type convertion were available.
`.nr X \\$1=\\$2` did not work for some input.

```
.de F
.nr X \\$1
.nr Y \\$2
.nr X \\nX=\\nY
\\nX
..
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GqvKL8tDQbG3VF9aWlJWm6FjeN9VJSFdy49PKKFCIUYmJUDMHMSBDTCC6aF2ELJCK5QCwuPT2o1jo9NwUlAwMDQyUFJUMFJa6SotJULpCYoYmpgRKEQhYGqgSpVgBKKUBZ6JIGEDmgRFpiTjHUNKCMkbESlGECk1KEuGLBAggNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Nạ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS_we7lq4pDgpuRgqsGCbkoGBoQEQKyjpKCgpQJgKShBZAA)

The "cast to integer" built-in (`N`) handles leading/trailing spaces and leading zeros. Then, we can just check equality with `ạ`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stratos](https://github.com/okx-code/Stratos), 3 bytes

```
_=_
```

Both of the `_` take an input as a string and convert it to a number, then negate it.

Java converts the input to a number by removing 0s and spaces.

The `=` takes the results of this and checks for equality

[Try it!](http://stratos.okx.sh/?code=_%3D_&input=0010000%0A%20%2010%20%20)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 1 [byte](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
=
```

Explanation

```
         Implicitly takes two inputs, and casts them to integers/floats if possible.
=        Checks if the two are equal
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f9v9/BQUDAwNjAwVOBS4gqaAAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## FALSE, 36 bytes

```
[0[^$9>][$32>[48-+10*]?]#%10/]$!\!=.
```

Numbers are received from the console, separated by a tab character.
True=`-1`, False=`0`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

Pretty boring.

```ruby
->a,b{a.to_i==b.to_i}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhZbde0SdZKqE_VK8uMzbW2TwHQtRO5mWYGCW7SSgYGBoZKOgpKhAhAoxXKBBQ1NTA3AgkAaLghUCFKsAJJQgDDR5MB6FIBySCYBJYyMwWaBWCZKsRDbFyyA0AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 29 bytes

```factor
[ [ " "without dec> ] same? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDRCoIwFIbvfYq/PYBsZTcFdhnddBNdiRfDJkqpYzsSIT772hSJwMPh8ME@/h9WyoI64@63y/V8gLS2KyyeyrTqhUZSFWtprDLQRhF9tKlbglVkcYyiIYKfAYxzLlhgMDHdcEZsQKZXiySSPV8kj@uSDwph/pFhJg/rUgjzK/jcF6RSvuyvz1vbHZv6Aib/1hi5DFkoetdUdT3hoYoUOaxs1Am5G7w8/UfaSI3YfQE)

Factor's number parser can't handle spaces so I have to remove them first.