# The Non-Zero Digital Product Challenge

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, integer

<sup>Originally the Multiplicative digital root</sup>

## Challenge

<sup><s><sup>Basically do what the title says</sup></s></sup>

## Method

Given a positive integer  **1** <= **N** <= **100000000** through one of our [standard input methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), multiply every digit together, ignoring zeroes.

**Ex:** Take a number, say `361218402`:

- `3` * `6` = `18`
- `18` * `1` = `18`
- `18` * `2` = `36`
- `36` * `1` = `36`
- `36` * `8` = `288`
- `288` * `4` = `1152`
- `1152` * `1` <sup>*(ignore zeroes or turn them into ones)*</sup> = `1152`
- `1152` * `2` = `2304`

**The output for `361218402` is `2304`**

***Note: Treat the digit `0` in numbers as `1`.***

## Test Cases

```
1 => 1
10 => 1
20 => 2
100 => 1
999 => 729
21333 => 54
17801 => 56
4969279 => 244944
100000000 => 1
```

[Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed, and this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest byte count wins!

Congrats to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) who got the bounty with [his 70 byte brain-flak answer!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153479/69912)

Comment: I'd rather call this *non-zero digital product*. "root" suggests it reduces to a single digit, which isn't always true here.

Comment: Can we take input as a string? Or (pushing it) an array of digits?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes, however, if you [repeat the process enough times](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98l3zDg/@H2wxOO7P//39jQyMTQyNgMhAE "Jelly – Try It Online"), it does appear to always go to a single digit.

Comment: You can take quoted input, but no, you can't take a pre-parsed list of digits if that's what you're asking

Comment: This seems like a variation on the [persistence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativePersistence.html) of a number.

Comment: If we have to support to a max of `100000000000` I suggest the test case `99999999999 => 31381059609`, since it doesn't fit in a default 32-bit integer. Perhaps better would be to lower the maximum output to a 32-bit maximum (2147483647).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ąžΠ
```

Explanation:

```
ą       Convert input to array of digits (implicit input as stack is empty)
 ž      Remove all zeroes from the array
  Π     Get the product of the elements of the array
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//SOvRfecW/P9vbGZoZGhhYmAEAA)

Comment: Surprised that this relatively new golfing lang is the only one that appears to be capable of solving this challenge in 3 bytes!

Comment: I was surprised by that too!

Answer (score 11):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
foldr((*).max 1.read.pure)1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUtLDsIgFLzKCyswSnjQtGXRI3gCdfHSgjZCJVQTTy9GNM5iZjKfC61XF0Lxw7H4W5gy5xshIz0BZXY0yfTITmCJNC8wQKS0B57yvNxBghdwYMi2wFB9WKuvr2KtrRkaY2rc9apuG9ta3dXStKixb5T@/f5gp/IafaDzWnZjSm8)

### Ungolfed with [UniHaskell](https://github.com/totallyhuman/unihaskell) and `-XUnicodeSyntax`

```hs
import UniHaskell

f ∷ String → Int
f = product ∘ map (max 1 ∘ read ∘ pure)
```

---

### Explanation

I'll start with what I initially had:

```hs
product.map(max 1.read.pure)
```

This is a *point-free* expression that evaluates to a function taking a string (or a list of characters) **s** (`"301"`) as an argument. It maps `max 1.read.pure` over **s**, essentially taking each character **i**, injecting it into a list (which makes it a string) (`["3", "0", "1"]`), then reading it, which evaluates the string (`[3, 0, 1]`) and finally taking the greater of **i** and **1** (`[3, 1, 1]`). Then it takes the `product` of the resulting list of integers (`3`).

I then golfed it by a byte with:

```hs
foldr((*).max 1.read.pure)1
```

This works because `product` is equivalent to `foldr (*) 1`. Instead of mapping and folding, I combined the two by folding with `(*).max 1.read.pure` which takes each non-zero digit and multiplies it with the accumulator.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<1or(n%10or 1)*f(n/10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU3LCsIwEDzrV8wlNJGI2URat6j/UpFgQbcltAe/Pq4enMMM84CZ38tjklhrvjyH1@0@QHo501SsGApTAbldtnKg4GpWKxgF5EHBI4avKjGzOkopadCdgvZHbjl2/Bv80W83cxllQWMorthfYdq1gYEVD31xrn4A)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Do1P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98l3zDg/@H2R01r/v@3tLTUUTCxNLM0MgcyjAwA) or see the **[test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98l3zDg/@H2R01r/v@PNtThMjTQ4TIyANFAwtLSEsgzNDY2BgqYWxgA5U0szSyNzC3BCuAgFgA)**

### How it works

```
Do1P - Main link. Argument: n (integer)  e.g. 1230456
D    - Digits                                 [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6]
 o1  - Replace 0 with 1                       [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6]
   P - Product                                720
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
cat(prod((x=scan()%/%10^(0:12)%%10)+!x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKOgKD9FQ6PCtjg5MU9DU1Vf1dAgTsPAytBIUxXI1NRWrNDU/G9sZmhkaGFiYPQfAA)

Since input is guaranteed to have no more than 12 digits, this should work nicely. Computes the digits as `x` (including leading zeros), then replaces zeros with `1` and computes the product.

```r
cat(					#output
    prod(				#take the product of
         (x=				#set X to
	    scan()			#stdin
		  %/%10^(0:12)%%10)	#integer divide by powers of 10, mod 10, yields digits of the input, with leading zeros. So x is the digits of the input
                                   +!x  #add logical negation, elementwise. !x maps 0->1 and nonzero->0. adding this to x yields 0->1, leaving others unchanged
                                      ))
```

Comment: So this is how to codegolf with R... Nice one ;) Still trying to figure out how this one works though!

Comment: @Florian I've added a more verbose explanation.

Comment: That's a new way to split digits that I'll have to try!

Comment: @BLT that's one of my [tips for golfing in R!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138046/67312)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 39 bytes

```c
k;f(n){for(k=1;n;n/=10)k*=n%10?:1;k=k;}
```

Needs to be compiled without optimizations (which is the default setting for gcc, anyway).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5BCsIwEEX3PUUoFBJRnElK2zgEL@JGIpESOkpxV3r2GHXb@Jfz/jy@P9y9TylSkKyW8JhldEhMfHQIKu4cNwjnE1J0kdY08ktM15GlqpZK5DznfAqybm4XrvciSNOhxqEFrRRtN7BMoIg0/PkqM2ttWYnGmLK1H6C8tLWd1f2GO1Px2/TNp7CmNw)

Comment: That `k=k;` putting `k` in the return register accidentally is just plain evil. You should _probably_ add that this only works without optimisations on possibly only x86/x64. +1.

Comment: @tomsmeding Somewhat surprisingly, it [does work on architectures other than x86](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152860/compare-two-numbers-given-as-strings/152861#comment373564_152861). No optimizations (`O0`) is the default for gcc, so there is no need for explicitly using that flag. I guess I'll add a mention of it to the post anyway.

Comment: You might want to specify the exact version of GCC it works with, for future proofing.

Comment: @moonheart08 I doubt that it would stop working after some version. Anyway, it works with the latest version, so the time of posting can be used to find a version with which it at least works.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>74</s> <s>72</s> 70 bytes

-2 thanks to Nitrodon for suggesting getting the negation of the number so that you only have to increment rather than decrement later

```
{([{}]((((()()()){}){}){}){}){({<({}())><>([[]](){})<>}<><{}>)<>}{}}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1ojuro2VgMENEFQs7oWCWlU22hU1wJF7WzsNKKjY2M1QMI2drU2djbVtXYgVnUtkPP/v7GZoZGhhYmB0X/dRAA)

There might be a few ways to golf this further, such as  <s>redoing the multiplication to avoid having to initialise the total with 1.</s> (-2 bytes)

#### How It Works:

```
{ Loop over every number
  ([{}]((((()()()){}){}){}){}) Add 48 to the negative of the ASCII to get the negation of the digit
  { If the number is not 0
     ({<({}())><>([[]](){})<>}<><{}>)<> Multiply the total by the number
                                          If the total is on an empty stack, add 1
  } 
  {} Pop the excess 0
}<> Switch to the stack with the total
```

Comment: You can golf two more bytes by computing the negation of the actual digit, then counting up to 0 instead of down to 0.

Comment: Dang it. I thought with the compression I finally beat a brain-flak answer, but then I ran the same algorithm on yours and got  only 26.25 bytes

Comment: @Dadsdy further brain-flak compression can get it down to ~19.81 bytes actually

Comment: @JoKing huh. How? I might steal that algorithm and shrink mine down more

Comment: @Dadsdy [Compressed brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161056/expand-compressed-brain-flak) drops it down to 50 bytes, times log_256(9). I'm not sure it's relevant, though perhaps you could replace `()`s with a single char

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
0KSP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fwDs44P9/E0szA0sjc0sA)

**Explanation**

```
0K     # remove zeroes
  S    # split to list of digits
   P   # product
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was a four way tie between Jelly, husk, and 05AB1E, and you answered first.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sub><s>17</s></sub> <sub><s>14</s></sub> 13 bytes

#### -4 bytes courtesy of @GalenIvanov

```
[:*/1>.,.&.":
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcSxCkBQFAbg3VP8GYg4zrlXOLdYlMlkNepKFmVQnv4yfN8ZYkp39A4pCjDcrySMyzyF1eWVDFRQQrELWeS348IO//j7hTAM/zNUFUastZC2Y0GtjZpWwwc)

Probably can be improved some. Edit: and so it was.

## Explanation

```
[: */ 1 >. ,.&.":
                 ": Convert to string
             ,.     Convert row to column vector
               &.   Convert to numbers
      1 >.        Maximum of each element with 1 (convert 0 to 1)
   */              Product
[:                 Cap fork
```

`&.`-under is a nifty adverb that applies the verb on the right, then the verb on the left, then the *inverse* of the verb on the right. Also converting back to numbers is technically using eval (`".`-do).

Comment: You can save a byte by changing `+0=]` to `*#]` [Try it online](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o6209B00tJRjNXX01PSUrP5rcqUmZ@QrpCmklqUWVSoYGigYGQBJAwVLS0sFI0NjY2MFQ3MLA0MFE0szSyNzy/8A)

Comment: `[:*/0-.~,.&.":` for 14 bytes. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o6209A109ep09NT0lKz@a3KlJmfkK6QppJalFlUqGBooGBkASQMFS0tLBSNDY2NjBUNzCwNDBRNLM0sjc8v/AA)

Comment: @GalenIvanov I knew that signum would be useful! My original thought was `(+-.@*)`, guess I'm inclined to add. I had tried using `'0'-.~` assuming an input of a string, not sure why it didn't cross my mind to do it on the split digits. Thanks!

Comment: `1>.` does the job of  `0-.~` for a byte less.
`[:*/1>.,.&.":`
[Try it!](https://tio.run/##DcSxCkBQFAbg3VP8GYg4zrlXOLdYlMlkNepKFmVQnv4yfN8ZYkp39A4pCjDcrySMyzyF1eWVDFRQQrELWeS348IO//j7hTAM/zNUFUastZC2Y0GtjZpWwwc)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda n:eval('*'.join(`n`.replace(*'01')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BDoIwEEX3nGJ2BdKYdlrAktSLAImoJWKwEKgmnh4RC7P6/@XnZYaPu/cW50aXc1c/L7cabG7edReSmBwefWvDsz0fRjN09dWEMWGcRFE0OzO5CTQUZVCIlCM/SoYUBZMVXRCnwP@BbQmXhJ7tUClFIUP1X3AhBIXEK7IjWzRJujapUoXZMkYplZSbZz8vrIKmH@H3HIXRTK/OQWvXPuUBDGNrnedaN@GPR3RdE30i1JP5Cw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 21 bytes

*Thanks to @Luis Mendo for saving a byte and thanks to @alephalpha for saving another byte!*

```
@(n)prod((k=n-48)+~k)
```

Takes input as a string of digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPs6AoP0VDI9s2T9fEQlO7Llvzf5qCrUJiXrE1F1eahrqxmaGRoYWJgZG6JohrCKUMILSRAYwPZVhaWkJlDI2NjaGS5hYGUH0mlmaWRuaWcE1woK75HwA)

**30 bytes:**

```
@(n)prod((k=num2str(n)-48)+~k)
```

Takes input as a number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPs6AoP0VDI9s2rzTXqLikCCiia2KhqV2Xrfk/TcFWITGv2JqLK03D2MzQyNDCxMBIE8gxBBMGINLIAMIGU5aWlmAxQ2NjY7CwuYUBWK2JpZmlkbklVCkcaP4HAA)

Comment: [`@(n)prod((k=n-48)+~k)`](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPs6AoP0VDI9s2T9fEQlO7Llvzf5qCrUJiXrE1F1eahrqxmaGRoYWJgZG6JohrCKUMILSRAYwPZVhaWkJlDI2NjaGS5hYGUH0mlmaWRuaWcE1woK75HwA "Octave – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils + sed + bc, <s>27</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```bash
tr 0 1|sed s/\\B/*/g|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIwUDBsKY4NUWhWD8mxklfSz@9Jin5/39DLkMDLiMDIGnAZWlpyWVkaGxszGVobmFgyGViaWZpZG4JkoMDLgA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

Designed for 32-bit integers.

```js
f=n=>!n||(n%10||1)*f(n/10|0)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=n=>!n||(n%10||1)*f(n/10|0)

console.log(f(1))        // => 1
console.log(f(10))       // => 1
console.log(f(20))       // => 2
console.log(f(100))      // => 1
console.log(f(999))      // => 729
console.log(f(21333))    // => 54
console.log(f(17801))    // => 56
console.log(f(4969279))  // => 244944
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
⊇ẹ×ℕ₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FX@8NdOw9Pf9Qy9VFT4///xmaGRoYWJgZG/6MA)

#### Explanation

```
⊇        Take a subset of the input
 ẹ       Split the subset into a list of digits
  ×      Product
   ℕ₁    This product must be in [1, +∞)
```

This works because `⊇` unifies from large subsets to small subsets, so the first one that will result in a non-zero product is when all zeroes are excluded and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>55</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```java
int f(int n){return n>0?(n%10>0?n%10:1)*f(n/10):1;}
```

Port of [*@Dennis*' Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153291/52210).
-1 byte thanks to *@RiaD*.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##XZDBbsIwDIbvPIWFNClZNRa3CEjLtifYieO0Q4AWBYpbNSnqhPrsXQjV1mIpsn7b@azfR3VRL0WZ0nF/6na5MgY@labrBMBYZfUOurygA2RMkwXi1yq1dUVA7@KD0RMKl28pRv6cMXpFwWNM2g6grLe5@95TLoXew9mR2cZWmg5f34rflgBkReXZ@g0TvUaR6CDgvgNgU2OZ5snkTzj@QIVi3BtJKeVoFqMoGo0vVwKHhblcyHApHxg@HtbcY1iMFhjiai5CX2zd@7@g93634nw2ve/Nj7HpeVbUdla6i9icWBNMY5gGGWt4j2m7Xw)

**<s>55</s> 54 bytes version:**

```java
n->{int r=1;for(;n>0;n/=10)r*=n%10>0?n%10:1;return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bVDLboMwELz3K1aRKpmiUBuiJI4L/YLmkmPVg0ucyilZkDERVcS3U/M4QJSVH9rZ1czOnuVVLvNC4fn426aZLEv4kBpvTwAarTInmSrYd2kPQEq6Fz3hkMZdd0orrU5hDwgxtLhMbl2LiZk45YYITKjA15hRz7zE@MxoQt@7b8eEUbYyCEY0rRi4iuo7c1wj5TXXR7i4ccjBGo0/n1/SG0bpmDsV7VT0G6NC@77XVwCsKi3R/YRj4rQnWUjntVnKOZ/1siiKZu2bLWVTYMXXPNzwO44@7mSGmILRmoVsu6Lhg3X23gcrzmc9@j78lVZdgryyQeE2YjMktb/YwcLHICW1NxI17T8)

Comment: you can save parens like this: `long f(long n){return n>0?(n%10>0?n%10:1)*f(n/10):1;}`

Comment: Sorry, [I'm claiming this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153423/16236) (45 bytes) because the algorithm is totally different ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 23 + 1 (`-p`) = 24 bytes

```perl
$\=1;s/./$\*=$&||1/ge}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxtbQulhfT18lRstWRa2mxlA/PbW2@v9/QwMj43/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Julia 0.6, 26 bytes

```
!x=prod(max.(digits(x),1))
```

Example of use:

```
julia> !54
20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BCsMgEEX3PYXJSqGEaEzsLAKlZ@gFbBWxNLZUA7m91QZqMoth3jw@/zE/rRxirJbx/XkpPMmlwcoaGzxeyJESEmdvnUEX6XVz1T4cziFtrwOq84HuSfga3bSxbnWowpSMIy3U7pBlZBu71wCQWDAoAdp1Xfr1vITEqc0l/fB/cRiAiZxlnAPn24J1fjXaqfgF)

Comment: could you add an example of how to call this, as well as a byte count? you can use [TIO](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fscK2oCg/RSM3sUJPIyUzPbOkWKNCU8dQU/P/fwA)!

Comment: @Giuseppe oops, I got distracted. I counted the length but didn't add it. Huh TIO supports julia now. Neat.

Comment: In fact, TIO supports Julia 0.4-0.6! very nice, +1.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 30 bytes

```javascript
f=([a,...b])=>a?(+a||1)*f(b):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRDkQwEADQ68wsJlqbjazgIOJjVCtEjLTiy93HexvfnFxcz6s4ZPaqoYWBcyKaRmw77iHj5zH4CTDh32jj5Eiye9plgQBnFOdTIo7LPdgRsVGtfsaa@lvaFw)

Takes **string** as an input, treats it as array, and by array destructuring separates the first element `[a,...b]`. `+a||1` returns digit corresponding to `a` character. I guess that rest is self explaining..

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
fꜝΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiZuqcnc6gIiwiIiwiMzYxMjE4NDAyIl0=)

Pyt isn't the only language to do 3 bytes :3

#### Explained

```
fꜝΠ
f   # flatten to a list
 ꜝ  # remove all 0's
  Π # product
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 88 bytes

Readable version:

```
#Push a 1 onto the alternate stack. Return to the main stack
(<>())<>

#While True:
{

    #Push the current digit minus 48 (the ASCII value of '0') onto the alternate stack
    ({}[((((()()()){}){}){}){}]<>)

    #If it's not 0...
    {
        (<

            #Multiply the top two values (the current digit and the current product that started at 1)
            ({}<>)({<({}[()])><>({})<>}{}<><{}>)

        #Also push a 0
        >)

    #Endwhile
    }

    #Pop the 0
    {}

    #Return to the main stack
    <>

#Endwhile
}

#Toggle to the alternate stack, and implicitly display
<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY2xCoBACIb3e4pGHQ5qqkF8kbjhGoIoGlrFZze9jlRU9Pt1e@px5/2qpxkQAyJxSpLS4AaiK4RhOIr@UYjxY6TlRpPzPgehJsSC7BedJ9bYkCij6wLWru7Vn3pHbDbNyzhZri8)

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYzBCoBACETvfkVHPQS1RXQQfyQ6bIcgig5dxW83d4NGGXF4zPbk4273K5/uyIJELAAK0IRQbcEiKkNq/670EYpabxFXnFaS6Akqikps1VlYTSL7XjUwCMB9mPrUz2OXvM0v)

Comment: I literally forgot I posted that comment, and rewrote it from scratch. I'm just going to post separately

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 56 bytes

```clj
(fn[n](apply *(replace{0 1}(map #(-(int %)48)(str n)))))
```

Pretty basic. Turns the number into a string, then subtracts 48 from each character to turn them back into numbers. It then replaces each 0 with a 1, and applies `*` to the resulting list of numbers (which reduces `*` over the list). Can accept a number, or a stringified number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vUVCUmVeSk6eg8V8jLS86L1YjsaAgp1JBS6MotSAnMTm12kDBsFYjN7FAQVlDVwOoVkFV08RCU6O4pEghTxME/isZmxkaGVqYGBgpAXkA)

```clj
(defn non-zero-prod [n]
  (let [; Abusing strings to get each digit individually
        str-n (str n)
        
        ; Then turn them back into numbers
        digits (map #(- (int %) 48) str-n)

        ; Substitute each 0 for a 1
        replaced (replace {0 1} digits)]
    
    ; Then get the product
    (apply * replaced)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>42</s> <s>40</s> <s>35</s> <s>32</s> 27 bytes

```
p eval (gets.chars-[?0])*?*
```

Assumes no newlines in input
[Major influence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153290/55458)

-2 bytes thanks to @GolfWolf

-5 bytes thanks to @Conor O'Brien

Comment: Even shorter than `tr`: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhtSwxR0EjPbWkWC85I7GoWDfa3iBWUy8rPzNPwV7r/39DcwsDQwMA)

Comment: @GolfWolf Clever :)

Comment: Might your perhaps use `*` to join? `p eval (gets.chars-[?0])*?*` ?

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>36</strike> 33 bytes

Simple Javascript (ES6) method that takes input as number string, spreads it into an array, then reduces it through multiplication or returns the value if the result is 0.

3 bytes saved thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)

```javascript
s=>[...s].reduce((a,b)=>b*a||a,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoMwDADQ/52kFRfWKmMg9SLiR9oG2RAjifPLu8f3fniiFvnux3PjSibJNI0TAOgMQvVfyDlss09jbvC6sA3ehkfhTXklWHlx4nbhQqqAspxTnL0fzLp3iOHTv@IN)

Comment: Save 3 bytes by taking input as a string.

Comment: I don't know why I thought it had to be converted, thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
!UXzp
```

Input is taken as a string

Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%21UXzp&inputs=%27361218402%27&version=20.6.0) Or [verify test cases in Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8F8xNKKq4L9LyH91Q3UudVMgNjQAEkYGYBaItLS0BAkYGhsbg8TMLQxAKk0szSyNzC0hquBAHQA)

#### Explanation

```
!     % Implicit input: string (row vector of chars). Transpose into
      % a column vector of chars
U     % Convert from string to number. Treats each row independently,
      % producing a column vector of numbers
Xz    % Keep only nonzeros
p     % Product. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
1<*_$#`.#0@#:+!:-"0"~$
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=MTwqXyQjYC4jMEAjOishOi0iMCJ+JA&input=MzYxMjE4NDAy)

**Explanation**

```
1<                        Push 1, turn back left, and push a second 1.       
                     $    Drop one of them, leaving a single 1, the initial product.

                -"0"~     Read a char and subtract ASCII '0', converting to a number.
             +!:          If it's 0, make it 1 (this is n + !n).
      `  0  :             Then test if it's greater than 0, to check for EOF.
   _                      If it is greater than 0, it wasn't EOF, so we continue left.
  *                       Multiply with the current product, becoming the new product.
1<                        Now we repeat the loop, but this time push only a single 1...
                     $    ...which is immediately dropped, leaving the current product.

   _                      On EOF, the input value will be negative, so we branch right.
    $                     We don't need the input, so drop it.
       .  @               Leaving us with the product, which we output, then exit.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 45 bytes

```java
s->s.chars().reduce(1,(a,b)->b<49?a:a*(b-48))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LasMwELznKwZDQEplYSduEudVein00FN6Kz3Ir1SpIxlLDoSQb3dlOzl1QbswM5phjuIsfF3l6pj9tvJU6dri6DDeWFnyyXr0DysalVqpVUdWTVLKFGkpjMGHkArXEXBHjRXWnbOWGU6OI3tbS3X4@oaoD4b2UuBTvyv7dvfcDJIdCmxb4@8MT39EbQjldZ41aU5CRgRLqL9LNlH8IlZiQhI/WlLarns3qazzt7mxBltcETJMGWYMEcMzw5xhwbBkiBnCwHFBd92KY4dMw9nMScPFMnD/ongeTxe98D64DSGFrkFcUp@zGtIedYD9xdj8xHVjeeXK2IJ44zAwK4yzsfJYL2couKiq8vJqXHvieU8dSungfxt179b@AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby + `-n`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13792/a-proposal-on-command-line-flags), 25 bytes

```ruby
p eval ($_.chars-[?0])*?*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhtSwxR0FDJV4vOSOxqFg32t4gVlPLXuv/f0MjYxNTg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA)

#### [Ruby (vanilla)](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```ruby
p eval (gets.chars-[?0])*?*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhtSwxR0EjPbWkWC85I7GoWDfa3iBWU8te6/9/QyNjE1MDAA)

Comment: Using `ruby -n` you can use `$_` instead of `gets` for -2!

Comment: @DomHastings Thanks, I'm pretty sure that flag still counts for 1 byte though

Comment: I believe the new consensus is Ruby + `-n` is counted as a different lang without the +1 for `-n`. [Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/9365)

Comment: @DomHastings [it's a proposal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13792/a-proposal-on-command-line-flags) but I'm not going to argue with fewer bytes

Answer (score 2):

## **[C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/), 97 Bytes (First code golf)**

```
static int X(int y){var z=y.ToString();int r=1;foreach(var q in z){if(q!=48){r*=q-48;}}return r;}
```

Not sure if i had to wrap it in a method or not so just included it to be safe.

Takes an Int in, converts it to a string and returns the multiple of each of the characters ignoring 0's. Had to minus 48 due to the program using the ascii value as it reads it as a char.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I no nothing of C#, but [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11927/71256) should help you understand the rules for golfing in it.

Comment: Thanks @H.PWiz I really am starting to love these little challenges, definitely making me change my regular programming to be more concise and efficient.

Comment: Welcome and nice first try :D Some tips for your answer: you can remove the `var z=y.ToString();` and place it directly in the `foreach`, like so: `foreach(var q in y.ToString())`; and to get the result you can save more bytes by replacing `{if(q!=48){r*=q-48;}}` with `r*=(q>48?q:1);`, shaving off the brackets and the `if`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 46 bytes

```cs
i.Select(c=>c>48?c-48:1).Aggregate((p,c)=>p*c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/BisIwEIbvPsVQPCSiJZMUbdRmWYQFwZuHPS9DLAGJ0saT@OxVSdDLYvuf/oHvG2aonVHrup@Lp/U@NM7XU9j6oKSBA1TgoDKdy/f2aCkwqgyZovyiWVEukeffdd3Y@i9Yxs5T4pU5T4h3q9Foc/Lt6Wjz38YFu3PeMhhnao4Sy0LIJVwP7D1m/JYBX/0vQQyKKKEYQstEyyE0itfuIbjWOuKP0otLVEqlW561V8BFKTCd86w9QqHnWi7SQWn4qDx@jHm9HJOk7g4)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 61 bytes

```
Listen to N
Cut N
O's 1
While N
Let O be*roll N-0 or 1

Say O
```

[Try it](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s>, 5 bytes

```
ṢU×\Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkWhh6fHPNzZ8P//f0MjY1MzAxMA)

Comment: 5 mins, not bad!

Comment: `DTịDP` would save a byte, but there are better ways to strip zeroes or replace them with something else.

Comment: *Multiplicative* root with *ṢUṀ*

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
f n=product[read[d]|d<-show n,d>'0']
```

Same byte count:

```hs
f n=product[max 1$read[d]|d<-show n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7agKD@lNLkkuig1MSU6JbYmxUa3OCO/XCFPJ8VO3UA99n9uYmaegq1CSj6XgkJBUWZeiYKKQpqCISrPAIVrZIAma6CAImBpaYmq3tDY2BhViaG5hQGqHSaWZpZG5pYK6EbDgQLXfwA)

Comment: [Also 36](https://tio.run/##XU3LCoMwELznK@bQQ@tp1xR1D/kXA2lo0ESxIv59Cj0U1jnNi5m3/0yvea41ghybiOJ4zP4c8xJQwNTEe0jHjz5q9qnAISwGWLdUdtwQwVqRki1dUoIyRET32VqrK9wPpD@e0knbC67Tf8DULw)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>11</s> 7 bytes

*4 bytes saved thanks to @EriktheOutgolfer*

```apl
×/0~⍨⍎¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TD0/UN6h71rnjU23doBVBIQd3YzNDI0MLEwEidC8gzNABTRgZQHoS2tLSECBsaGxtDZMwtDAzBLBNLM0sjc0uYejhQBwA)

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TD0/UN6h71rnjU23doBVBIQd3YzNDI0MLEwEidC8gzNABTRgZQHoS2tLSECBsaGxtDZMwtDAzBLBNLM0sjc0uYejhQBwA) (although I doubt you can take the number as a string, but then still [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TD0/UN6h71rnjU23doxaOOGY96pwIlFNSNzQyNDC1MDIzUuYA8QwMwZWQA5UFoS0tLiLChsbExRMbcwsAQzDKxNLM0MreEqYcDdQA))

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,v=1:n and f(n/10,n%10*v or v)or v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrBCsIwEETP@hV7kbay4G5S2m4h/oh4iJRgQbellIBfHxMPDsMbZnfWz/5c1KQU3Mu/H5MHxeh4VPA6Qaj1woR6YjpHWDaITUEKhTAr3GzHhoeWDAJnE4Khkhkikhtba/OhHyj/W@nE9PIb/HUfj4d1m3WHiJW7Vhjq2KQv)

2 bytes thx to Lynn.

Comment: `f(n/10,n%10*v or v)` saves 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 19 bytes

```
1i:&0(?n&c4*-:0=+*!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3zDTSs1Awz5PLdlES9fKwFZbS/H/fxNLMwNLI3NLAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 12 bytes

```
L,EDBFEZB]B*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx9XFyc01yinWSev///@GRsYmBqZmAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 55 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@n=prod[toInt c-48\\c<-:toString n|c>'0']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxCsIwEADQ3a@4rVNApKgRKx10KLhltA7hUksguSvptSD47Z6@/WEaPGnmsKQBso@kMU9cBJyEG62blpqpcHgIdySApj72PZ7NSdhJiTQCffBSbaunOvH/1kALtd3b3cGCfvGV/Dir6e56fZPPEecf)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 9 bytes

```
×/(⍎¨⎕)~0
```

Prompts for screen input as a character string, convert to digits, drop zeros and multiply all.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 5 bytes

```
ì f ×
```

[Test it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=7CBmINc=&input=MzYxMjE4NDA=)

---

### Explanation

In order: split to an array of digits, filter to remove zeroes and reduce by multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

**Solution:**

```
*/1|.:'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0vfsEbPSl3J2MzQyNDCxMBI6f9/AA)

**Example:**

```
*/1|.:'"4969279"
244944
```

**Explanation:**

Convert the input string to a list of integers, take max compared to `1` (inspiration from the [J](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153285/69200) solution) and then multiply over the list.

Evaluation is performed right to left.

```
*/1|.:' / the solution
    .:' / value (.:) each (')
  1|    / or with 1 ( 0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>2 )
*/      / multiply (*) over (/)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 62 bytes

```forth
: f 1 swap begin ?dup while 10 /mod -rot 1 max * swap repeat ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBDsIgEETvfMWkR5MiyEGxUb8FLbRNrGwopv49svbgHHY2kzcTYspjOwS2Us4I0FhWR7j7YXrh1r8J6zg9PbTCfo492hRzhWb3wW5DkyfvMrpaJ3BBQja4XNHUOYlHQic0SNQFEgf1@/haaznQxhjOjie1UX@Byhc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 45 bytes

```lua
a=1(...):gsub("[^0]",load("a=a*..."))print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/0dZQQ09PT9Mqvbg0SUMpOs4gVkknJz8xRUMp0TZRCyilpKlZUJSZV6KRqPn//39jM0MjQwsTAyMA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>10</s> 9 Bytes

```
.U*s!BsZs
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.U%2as%21BsZs&input=%22361218402%22&debug=1)

### Explanation

```
.U*s!BsZs
.U        Q     Fold over the implicit input string
      sZ        Convert each char to int
   s!B          Form the list [d,not d] and sum it, so that 0 becomes 1
  *     sb      Multiply by the prev product (implicit). s needed because 1st value is char
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>33</s> 32 bytes

Feels like ages since I've done an array mapping solution in JS!

Takes input as a string.

```js
n=>[...n].map(x=>t*=+x||1,t=1)|t
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(f=
n=>[...n].map(x=>t*=+x||1,t=1)|t
)(i.value="361218402");oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 19 bytes

```perl6
{[*] grep +*,.comb}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##RY5LbsIwEIb3c4oRQhUhAeIHDpYV1G333bUs2mRaRQqJlYSqCHGy7nqx1DYR9Wbmf3wjW@pqNZ56wi@1Lgwcz/hQtCVhPl5elgf87MhivEzWRXt8v44ufhyoHzDHumqo//0JwWLzWsabyKmnZjDgzz27lgFbvzUYB8TAR9tN9GqPi3nV2NOQzOnbUjFQGeEFEKt@VRLZ@oz@F1MpSvBeS3B2MzHf/7szA9dRKMbZTqbcR1ykEpjfGLD0NnmY3OnJ0Fr7JeMaOBNCeLF1WLZLA7pVILXSPAs1LqWW0tP3F878AQ)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  [*]        # reduce using &infix:«*»

    grep     # find the values
      +*,    # that aren't "0"
      .comb  # split ｢$_｣ into digits (returns single character strings)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 78 bytes

```
@set/ap=%2+0,p+=!p,d=%1%%10,p*=d+!d,n=%1/10
@if %1 gtr 0 %0 %n% %p%
@echo %2
```

Previous 80-byte solution:

```
@set/an=%1,p=1
:l
@set/ad=n%%10,p*=d+!d,n/=10
@if %n% gtr 0 goto l
@echo %p%
```

(This version outputs 1 for an input of zero, rather than failing.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
Prod##Max&1=>Digits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fZmX7P6AoP0VZ2TexQs3Q1s4lMz2zpPi/X2pqSnG0SkFBcnosF1dAUWZeSUhqcYlzYnFqcXSajoKBlaV6tKGBjpGBjqGBgY6lpaWOkaGxsbGOobmFgaGOiaWZpZG5JUgOAmJj/wMA) Function that takes an integer as an argument and returns an integer.

### Explanation

This first takes the `Digits` of the input number, then each number's `Max` with `1` is taken, then the `Prod`uct is taken.

### Other solutions

```
Prod@Larger&1@Digits
Prod@Map[Max&1]@Digits
Prod@Map&:(Max&1)@Digits
{Prod[Max&1=>Digits[_]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 40 bytes

Sad to see `dc` so underrepresented here.

This is essentially my first code golf post, so if I've misjudged how bytes should be counted, go easy on me!  :)

```
?[1+]sc[10~rdZ1<a]dsax1[rd0=c*z1<b]dsbxp
```

You can run this in the terminal like so:

```
$ echo 361218402 | dc -e '?[1+]sc[10~rdZ1<a]dsax1[rd0=c*z1<b]dsbxp'
2304
```

Or you can [try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98@2lA7tjg52tCgriglytAmMTalOLHCMLooxcA2WavK0CYJKJBUUfD/v6GZgTkA)

---

Explanation (probably too verbose):

```
? # Read and execute a line from standard input
  # (A number just goes on the stack)
[ # Begin a literal string (ended by a matched ']')
1 # Push 1 onto the stack (when this string is executed as a macro)
+ # Pop top two numbers, add them, push result
] # End literal string
s # Pop top of stack (the string) and store it in...
c # ...register c
[
10 # Push 10 (duh)
~ # Pop top two numbers, divide second popped by first popped, push quotient and then remainder
r # Reverse top two numbers of stack
d # Duplicate top of stack (pop and then push it twice)
Z # Pop top of stack and push its length in digits
1
< # Pop two numbers and compare; if first popped is less than second then...
a # ...run macro stored in register a (a recursive call, here)
] # End string
d # Duplicate top of stack
s # Store in...
a # ...register a
x # Execute the top of stack!
  # At this point the stack will consist of one digit entries, the digits of input
1
[
r # Reverse
d # Duplicate
0
= # If top two numbers are equal then...
c # ...run macro in register c
* # Pop two, multiply, push product
z # Push "height" of stack
1
< # If height of stack is greater than 1 then...
b # ...run macro b
]
d # Duplicate the string on the stack
sb # Store it as macro b
x # Execute!
p # Print top of stack
```

Comment: Always nice to see `dc` around :) I added a TIO link, hope you don't mind - feel free to rollback if you don't like my edit.

Comment: @BMO thanks!  And I don’t know if this is maximally golfed; it’s pretty straightforward implementation.

Comment: You might be able to get rid of the first macro and `0=c` with [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125893/48198) tip, but I haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 1):

## Microsoft Excel - <s>62</s> 47 Bytes

```
{=PRODUCT(IFERROR(1/(1/MID(A1,ROW(A:A),1)),1))}
```

## Explanation

Converts value in cell A1 to array of digits, changes 0s to 1s using absolute value, then multiplies.

*15 bytes saved thanks to Engineer Toast*

Comment: Save 15 bytes: `{=PRODUCT(IFERROR(1/(1/MID(A1,ROW(A:A),1)),1))}`. It drops zeroes by trying to divide by them to get an error. You can drop the `INDIRECT` stuff, too, because dividing by blank text values will also give you an error. All the errors are replaced by `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
ΠfId
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yCNM@U////G5sZGhlamBgYAQA)

```
ΠfId  -- implicit input N, for example 1607
   d  -- digigts: [1,6,0,7]
 fI   -- filter by identity function: [1,6,7]
Π     -- product: 42
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 58 bytes

```
f=a=>{b=1;for(i=0;a[i];i++){(a[i]>0)&&(b=+b*a[i])}alert(b)
```

Input via function(arg) outputs alert

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 68 bytes

```
func[n][p: 1 while[n > 0][d: n // 10 n: n / 10 if d > 0[p: p * d]]p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcwxDsIwDIXhvad4M0udBlGcgUOwRh4qnIpIyIoqUI8fFIaG7dPzL29J6z0pogxLqOvHHtEklgCH/ZlfKRpuIIkaYBhHOIL92JRXaDu3vuAEFSlSy5btjQVuOEQHJ/pbu5m5J85736v5Sv3TmS88zVy/)

Since 100000000000 is beyond the integer range of the Red language, here's another approach that solves this issue, using string manipulation:

Red, 74 bytes

```
func[n][p: 1 foreach c to-string n[if c >#"0"[p: p * to-integer c - 48]]p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDoMgFEV3v@LFbk1MQEz1OfQjupI3EATLggTp91NcwDud3Htyo9nyx2wgqVNrtj@vpScZVuBgj2iU/oKGdAxnis7v4KWzpXg/etZfVoDntTqfzG5iWQaYFqJAORQ/gQLeVWIVR3ZrGyNiU7gQolnzwtrThC8cZ7x/1OQ/)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 83 bytes

```
	DEFINE('O(N)')
O	O =1
R	N LEN(1) . X REM . N	:F(RETURN)
	X =EQ(X) 1
	O =O * X	:(R)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYwxC8IwEEbny6@4LXcO0qtFpNCtVxD0oiGBzJ3FDv5/0rg4OH18D977vLd1ew0VZl2upuQDGXuGkRL/Qxcg4CQuguFNjYTxiAWj3tsajAtFTTkaOyg46ZMKo7ivE/CApTUj1wQhp0dODZI/naWXy9D1La4219/fAQ)

A function that takes input as a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 33 bytes

```julia
x->prod(filter(x->x>0,digits(x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BCoMwEEX3niK4SqAtmkTTWURKz9AL2BolRWwxEXL7NFFodBbDvPn8@cx7GXVb@14@1aAn787Nd/50uNejVTMO6Jri1OlBW4MdIcSrqcsWo6cB3VujLg9lbHazoRtlUR4H9AqCydF6cdNQj0siZZmoOCCNSHfqUQaAwIJCMpSMsbCreDKJaxFDqvq/4lADFdFLOQfO9wFbrTHhJf8D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
*FsMs#Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8ut2LdYOfD/fyUTSzNLI3NLJQA)

---

```
*FsMs#Q Full program, takes input in "" from stdin and prints to stdout
    s#Q Filter input for truthiness of int-parse(digit), then
  sM    map int-parse to this,
*F      then fold over multiplication
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 78 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq

n=>n.Replace("0","").Select(c=>c-'0').Aggregate(1,(a,b)=>a*b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEAXv/YqlFxOpodpjbUEETwqiB8/rug2BmmgSBZF@e20FweM8huFRmJHz3D@CsRqOrxD5Wib/pLbG3suEWgwB9t5pj9d3AhAiRkPwdOYCOzRWyHEF2DwsLUP0QyEzNtbQQNXbqrbqwLcWiUWap1maSnXklikKqmqaTfKJVCutPWuMLOaZwOwsqxqnZ9mP2fIbXzsbXMvq5M1gNeLHB8bL8JOFlHI0u6TrF/OiKD4)

Comment: Smaller is  n=>n.Select(c=>c-'0').Aggregate(1,(a,b)=>a*(b==0?1:b));   You ought to include the terminating ';'

Comment: Following @user230118 suggestion, you can shrink it more by replacing `'0'` with `48`, and `(b==0?1:b)` with `(b>0?b:1)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 34 bytes

```
n->fold((a,b)->a*(b+!b),digits(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y4tPydFQyNRJ0lT1y5RSyNJWzFJUyclMz2zpFgjT1Pzf0FRZl6JRpqGsZmhkaGFiYERUAwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
*F #sM
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8tNQbnY9/9/JUNzCwNDJQA)

Explanation:

```
    sM   Get digits of implicit string input
   #     Filter on identity, removing 0s
*F       Fold on multiplication
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 7 bytes

```
$*YaDC0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@F/9X0UrMtHF2eB/rYKvQjSXgrGZoZGhhYmBEZeCIRAZcCkYGYBoIGFpaQnkGRobGwMFzC0MgPImlmaWRuaWYAUQwBX7/79uDgA)

`D`elete `C`haracter `0` from the argument `a` and fold (`$`) on multiplication (`*`). The `Y`ank operator is used to adjust the precedence of the subexpression (one byte shorter than `$*(aDC0)`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Dḟ0P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4Y75BgH///83MgUA)

```
Dḟ0P    main link

D       int to dec
 ḟ0     filter out 0
   P    product of list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 14 bytes

```
1<*+!:-0'~.j@#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//83tNHSVrTSNVCv08tyUP7/39jM0MjQwsTACAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)<sup>CP437</sup>

```
┤caü
```

5 bytes when unpacked,

```
E0-k*
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%E2%94%A4ca%C3%BC&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A20%0A100%0A999%0A21333%0A17801%0A4969279%0A100000000&a=1&m=2)

### Explanation

```
E         Convert number to digits
 0-       Remove all zeros
   k*     Reduce array with multiplication
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 52 bytes

```
n->(n+"").chars().reduce(1,(x,y)->x*=(y-=48)>0?y:1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4xb8IwEIX3/AqLyW6JFSeoYKKEDalDJ8aqg3Hs1BCcyHYQUZTffjUVN7x3d7r36S7iLtJLcwXZCe/RlzB2TowNymkhFTrOsUcaP9WSckmG8dwZiXwQIdq9Nw26xQw@BWds@/2DhGs9mZMj0qgCm9bYvq9WhMpf4Twm1KlmlAqzNX6sJ5LWj7cKT2m12ZE6O0x7RkrQvXvhkN//406TD@pG@zHQIe5DZ7GmGn/GN1vl6BDRKg7YE0LKZFkAWPYq2PAPnm85sO0uY5CzoiiAc/68gDyLBuwP)

Obligatory stream answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.extras math.unicode`, 21 bytes

```factor
[ 48 v-n nonzero Π ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU09DoIwGN05xbsAhlIiVA9gXFyMk3Fo8CMy0EIp4E9cvIYLiw7uXsPd2yjWN7zf4V3vmUytNv37slrOF7MJCml3o5aGsnaB9tbIv29UnuotoTRk7aE0ubKoqWpIpVSj6jD1vKo7gSEERwQWIAy-HEAIgZBxzsHiJGCIxFiEsRg2B5xvjc385LlGlKD1FZRWRzIarx4btz0KWaL83bqi751-AA)

Takes input as a string and gives output as an integer.

- `48 v-n` Subtract 48 from each code point in the input, converting it to a list of digits.
- `nonzero` Take only the non-zero numbers.
- `Π` Calculate the product of a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 bytes

```
0op
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWiw3yC5YUJyUXQ_kLVhqbGRoZWpgYGEEEAA)

##### Explanation

```python
0op  # Implicit input
0o   # Remove 0s
  p  # Product
     # (Yes, both of those work on numbers)
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [(,)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/(,)), 175 Chars or \$175\log_{256}(3)\approx34.67\$ Bytes

```
(()()()(),()()()()()()())(()(),())(,((),(())(),,,(()()())(),(())(()()()(),,,,(),,(()()()())))(()(),(()(),,,,(),,(())))((),(,,,,,())),,,(,(()()(),((()))))(()()()),())(,,(()()))
```

[TIO](http://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/?code=(()()()(),()()()()()()())(()(),())(,((),(())(),,,(()()())(),(())(()()()(),,,,(),,(()()()())))(()(),(()(),,,,(),,(())))((),(,,,,,())),,,(,(()()(),((()))))(()()()),())(,,(()()))&stdin=01234005)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 52 Bytes

```
$t=1;foreach(array_filter(str_split($n))as$b)$t*=$b;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 67 bytes

```
(load library
(d f(q((N)(i N(*(i(mod N 10)(mod N 10)1)(f(/ N 10)))1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxDoMwEAR7XrHlHg0@XBB/wn9wZFk6yQQCNLzeWEqRZjSaYi773NXOvTXWLWVUex/puAdmFH7JKDREjjSuW0aEOvmbCgunn4to45p2FLAfL2ivmF2nQwgBs3rvocvLqUh7AA)

#### Explanation + ungolfed

The function `f` computes the non-zero digit product of its argument `N`. It uses a divmod algorithm to process the digits: If `N` is nonzero, it computes (`N` mod 10 if `N` mod 10 is nonzero, `1` otherwise), and multiplies that quantity by the result of recursing on `N` divided by 10. Once `N` becomes zero, all the digits have been processed and we return `1`.

```
(load library)

(def digit-product
 (lambda (num)
  (if num
   (*
    (if (mod num 10) (mod num 10) 1)
    (digit-product (/ num 10)))
   1)))
```

---

This implementation commits the cardinal sin of not using tail recursion. It's not a problem for the size of number this challenge requires us to handle, but for big enough numbers, we would eventually hit the max recursion depth. Here's a proper tail-recursive implementation (with helper function) in **83 bytes**:

```
(load library
(d _(q((N P)(i N(_(/ N 10)(*(i(mod N 10)(mod N 10)1)P))P
(q((N)(_ N 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0xCsMwFEP3nkKjfpf6x0PrSxjfwLiYgMFp0jRLTu84pXQREtJDW3nttXyW1ljnlFHLc03rfmFG5Jv0CMICz8gbPNQIryyc5vxLf6cSRMIJjl9QGM@icUoLRrC/bNC@xGC6GjjnMKi1Fnp/GBVpBw)

Ungolfed:

```
(load library)

(def _digit-product
 (lambda (num accum)
  (if num
   (_digit-product
    (/ num 10)
    (*
     (if (mod num 10) (mod num 10) 1)
     accum))
   accum)))

(lambda (num) (_digit-product num 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 29 bytes

```arturo
$=>[∏filter digits&=>[0=&]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?iJ8CUI)

```
$=>[                   ; a function; assign input to &
    ∏                  ; product of...
    filter digits&=>[  ; digits of the input that aren't...
        0=&            ; equal to zero
    ]                  ; end filter
]                      ; end function
```